# Error while trying to fetch org details into Force

Tags: force.com, eclipse

Hi trying to create a package to move it from sandbox to prod via Force.com. When I try to do it and input my login credentials as well with my secur token i get the following error.
[image]

I am, using eclipse luna 4.4.1

I am really new to this so please spare me in case of misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution may help you.

You may face this issue because of firewall settings and configuring proxy server settings will do the trick.Please go through below link for detailed steps of the solution.

http://aluniya.blogspot.in/2013/12/unable-to-fetch-organization-details-for.html

Please Accept my answer as solution (if it was helpful) to make it available to others for similar problem.